# Including CSS in MasterPages

Tags: asp.net

I am new to the domain. I want to include a CSS file in my master pages,but it is not working can anyone try to help me out of this problem..

I give the link to the CSS externally as

```
<link href="Stylesheet1.css" rel="Stylesheet1" type="text/css" />
```

Is there any necessity to include CSS classes in master page if so how and where I have to include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<link href="~/Stylesheet1.css" rel="Stylesheet1" type="text/css" />
```

Tilde (~) represent root directory.

If this doesn't work, if you can show us your directory structure, and look at the rendered source we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course not use the Tilde (~) on tags that are not run server-side, what you have to do is something like this:

```
<link href="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Stylesheet1.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Or just do a method that gives you back a full link-tag.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the syntax of  your `<link>` tag. The problem is likely to be caused by the fact that your CSS file isn't located at the URL you're attempting to get it from.

The `href` attribute in your markup specifies a file called `Stylesheet1.css` in the **same folder** as your master page. If its not you should specify the location of the stylesheet using standard, virtual path or move the stylesheet to the same folder as your masterpage.

More info.

http://w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp